# WEPopoverController isn't showing the arrowhead - works the same as UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code for when the user presses a button:

```
SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    WEPopoverController *popover = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:settingsViewController];
    [popover setDelegate:self];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:settingsWheel.frame
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                           animated:YES];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(150, 200)];
```

Then in settings view controller, I have this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {


        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(150, 200);
    }
    return self;
}
```

But for some unknown reason, it's only showing the blue square of the background and not the arrowhead, or rounded corners.

Any ideas how I get it to show these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code for appearing the Popover (i have taken from WEPopoverTableView class on github)

```
UIViewController *contentViewController = [[WEPopoverContentViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

CGRect frame = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame;

self.popoverController = [[[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:frame 
                                            inView:self.view 
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                          animated:YES];

currentPopoverCellIndex = indexPath.row;
[contentViewController release];
```

Comment: why do you need to `contentSizeForViewInPopover` (setframe) in `initWithNibName` method? Is there any special case? if not, then this code is enough for button click.

Comment: `SettingsViewController` what is the purpose of this class in button click? If any thing more that you can say about your code??

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are including the images that come with WEPopoverController on GitHub. It includes arrows in all directions as well as backgrounds for the popover.